# Airflow does not update the progress of a dag/task to be completed even though the dag/task has actually completed

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have set up airflow to be running in a distributed mode with 10 worker nodes. I tried to access the performance of the parallel workloads by triggering a test dag which contains just 1 task which just sleeps for 3 seconds and then comes out.

I triggered the dag using the command 
airflow backfill test_dag -s 2015-06-20 -e 2015-07-10

The scheduler kicks of the jobs/dags in parallel and frequently I see the below o/p:
[2017-06-27 09:52:29,611] {models.py:4024} INFO - Updating state for  considering 1 task(s)
[2017-06-27 09:52:29,647] {models.py:4024} INFO - Updating state for  considering 1 task(s)
[2017-06-27 09:52:29,664] {jobs.py:1983} INFO - [backfill progress] | finished run 19 of 21 | tasks waiting: 0 | succeeded: 19 | kicked_off: 2 | failed: 0 | skipped: 0 | deadlocked: 0 | not ready: 0

Here the kicked_off:2 indicates that 2 tasks are kicked off but when I see the UI for the status of the dag runs, I see 2 instances of dags to be running. When i look into the respective task instance log, it indicates that the task has been successfully completed but still the above message is displayed in the command prompt infinitely

[2017-06-27 09:52:29,611] {models.py:4024} INFO - Updating state for  considering 1 task(s)
[2017-06-27 09:52:29,647] {models.py:4024} INFO - Updating state for  considering 1 task(s)
[2017-06-27 09:52:29,664] {jobs.py:1983} INFO - [backfill progress] | finished run 19 of 21 | tasks waiting: 0 | succeeded: 19 | kicked_off: 2 | failed: 0 | skipped: 0 | deadlocked: 0 | not ready: 0

Is it that the messages which are being sent by the worker is getting dropped and hence the status is not getting updated?

Is there any parameter in airflow.cfg file which allows the failed jobs like these to be retried on other worker nodes instead of infinately waiting for the message for the worker node which is responsible for executing the aobe failed tasks..